# Making input text responsive

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, textinput

I need to make the text input field in responsive. Currently, it matches width of other input elements, but when I decrease my screen size, the input field does not respond accordingly.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-8">
<table border="0"  id="dynamic_field">  
          <tr>  
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Digite o link da arquitetura" class="form-control"
            id="txt-link[]" name="txt-link[]" value="{{old('txt-link[]')}}" style="width: 730px;">
            @if($errors->has('txt-link.0'))
              @foreach ($errors->get('txt-link.0') as $message)
                <span class="help-block" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:-5px; color:rgb(170, 56, 56)"><b>{{  $message }}</b></span>
              @endforeach  
            @endif  </td>  
            <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" 
            <a class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </a></button></td>  
                </tr>  
          </table>  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not fixed your width. Remove `style="width: 730px;"`

You have to give your table width `100%`. In Bootstrap 4 there is a class `w-100` to do that.

```
<table border="0"  id="dynamic_field" class="w-100"> 
----
</table>
```

I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, it did not work. When I applied the proposed solution, the width decreased a lot. I need to keep the width of that field to be the same width of other fields in the form.

Comment: I used your code to solve your problem. Give me jsfiddle.